# Is taking the derivative inside this integral acceptable?

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have run into an integral where I take the partial derivative of x when the upper limit of the integral is x.  This is how I solve it but I am not sure if this is correct.  Can someone please check?  Thank you!
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_0^xf(t)dt=\int_0^x\frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial x}dt=0 $$

Comment: No.  Recall the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Okay, that is what I was worried about.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

No.

Assuming that $x$ does not appear free in $f(t)$, then by the *fundamental theorem of calculus*:

$$\dfrac{\partial ~~}{\partial x}\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm d t=f(x)$$

Comment: One has to assume $f \in L^1$. Moreover, $f$ will depend only on $x$, so it should be the usual derivative, not a partial derivative